# JavaScript if number < 10 add a "0"

Tags: javascript

I made a simple countdown with JavaScript, here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/PCwx8/

It simply counts to midnight today. My problem is that I simply want JavaScript to prepend a "0" to the numbers that are less than 10. I have an idea like:

```
if (i<10)
{
    i="0" + i;
 }
return i;
```

But I don't know whether it's an integral or simply a number? Thanks for the help, I normally have nothing to do with JavaScript, so please understand!

Comment: so what's the question?  The code you've given is the normal solution (albeit it's often wrapped up in a little function so you can call the same logic for hours, minutes and seconds).

Comment: the code i showed you doesnt work! How do i insert it in my fiddle example?

Comment: Well, you put the code in a function, lets call it `pad` and then call `seconds = pad(seconds);`. If you haven't even tried to integrate the code, how can you claim that it does not work?

Comment: @FelixKling Lets not call it pad, but something meaningful instead. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write and use a function like this:

```
function addZeroIfNeeded(val){
    return val < 10 ? "0" + val : val;   
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/VafZ7/

Comment: the ternary operator is a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `("0" + seconds).slice(-2)`.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PCwx8/2/).

```
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML= ("0" + hours).slice(-2);
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML= ("0" + days).slice(-2);
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML= ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. You first add something, and then remove it again most of the time...

Comment: sometimes i have upp to three numbers! For example when i count days of year! But thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here  you go: http://jsfiddle.net/PCwx8/3/

```
var seconds = 60-aseconds;
if(parseInt(seconds,10) <10){
    seconds = "0"+seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS will almost definitely parse the `"0"` as an integer and add zero to `i`. A bit cumbersome but working is the following:

```
var i = 0;
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + ("" + i);
}
return i;
```

The trick is, to make sure, that `i` will become a string. Similar to making an integer a string with `numericalStringvar * 1`

Comment: Nope, if one operand is a string, string concatenation is performed.

Comment: yep, try it in the console. "0"+1 goes to  "01"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the question is, however you can generalize with something like that:

```
function lead(str, num) {
    return (str + num).slice(-str.length);
}

function leadzero(num) {
    return lead("00", num);
}

console.log(leadzero(2)) // 02
console.log(leadzero(10)) // 10
```

Of course if you're in an environment that supports [ECMAScript5's bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), `leadzero` can be done in this way:

```
var leadzero = lead.bind(null, "00");
```